# libgdx timer number flickering instead of stopping - simple fix?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

pretty much i have a box on screen if u click out side the box the timer stops, if the time runs out it should out put 0.00.  when i stop the clock the time out put flickers between 4.51 and 4.53 as an example. and when it gets to 0 it flickers between -0.00 and 0.
any ideas? here my render method:

```
public void render(float delta) {

    label.updateText("SCORE: " + toString(score));
    seconds.updateText(String.format("time: %,.2f", time));
    time -= delta;
    //time is started 10

    if (time <= 0.001)
        currentState = GameState.GAMEOVER;

    switch (currentState) {

        case RUNNING:
            Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 1, 1);
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            stage.act(delta);
            stage.draw();
            break;


        case GAMEOVER: {
            go.setPosition(200, 400);
            stage2.act(delta);
            stage2.draw();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, updating your question has essentially the same effect as deleting it and asking it again...it will jump back up the listings. And then you wouldn't have lost earlier helpful comments for future readers. I really think you need to show more of your code. There is no explanation for this happening unless `time` is being affected somewhere else. One trick you can try is renaming `time` without refactoring, so you are forced to find every spot it was used and manually change the name. This is how I find spots where I might be modifying a variable without knowing it.

Comment: By the way...you are missing a screen clear in your game over state.

Comment: i had more code and a moderator told me to take it down. and what do you mean renaming time?

Comment: He means to simply rename the time variable WITHOUT letting your IDE refactor all other occurences of time. So you will notice where in your code time is manipulated and hence can track down the reason for your problem.

Comment: what ? omg thats even worse then the first one haha im so confused